# How to check if array contain a value

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create if condition with explicitly defined array:

So "standard" is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] number = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    if(contains(number, 2)){
        System.out.println("Array contain number 2");
    }

}

public static boolean contains(final int[] array, final int v) {

    boolean result = false;

    for(int i : array){
        if(i == v){
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

But how should I create something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    if(contains({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 2)){
         System.out.println("Array contain number 2");
    }

}
```

Because I am getting an error `Array initializer is not allowed here`

Comment: `if(contains(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 2)){`

Comment: You could change the signature of contains to this: `contains(int v, int... array)` then you can call it like this: `contains(2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)`

Answer (score 2):

Already people have answered in comment section, But here I am showing you how you can do it in Java8, if you are looking for some fancy way like this :

```
boolean result = Arrays.stream(array).anyMatch(x->x==2)
```

or By using IntStream.

```
boolean result = IntStream.of(array).anyMatch(x -> x == 2)
```